# Visual Studio 2019 Xaml Editor: Project Code button is disabled

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Throughout my project on every xaml file the Project Code button in designer view is disabled.
What could be possibly causing this?
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WUwi.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derive from Note in document [To disable project code in the designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/debugging-or-disabling-project-code-in-xaml-designer?view=vs-2019#to-disable-project-code-in-the-designer)

For projects that target ARM or X64 processors, Visual Studio cannot run project code in the designer, so the **Disable project code button is disabled** in the designer.

Comment: Ah! That's a bummer. Thanks.